# How to remove handlers from root logger

Tags: logging, quarkus

I want to set up centralized logging for my quarkus application and found [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/centralized-log-management) which recommends `gelf` as a tool to send messages to Logstash.

Enabling the gelf-handler does produce output, however the handler is immediately registered to the root-logger and I want to only specific loggers to log to gelf.

In short: I would something like this in my `application.properties`

```
quarkus.log.level=INFO
# This seems to not be possible
# quarkus.log.handlers=console,file
quarkus.log.category."org.acme".level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."org.acme".use-parent-handlers=true
quarkus.log.category."org.acme".handlers=gelf

quarkus.log.handler.gelf.enabled=true
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.host=tcp:localhost
quarkus.log.handler.gelf.port=12201
```

How can I achieve this effect?